# Slow UX Javascript execution with requirejs

Tags: javascript, requirejs

We added `requirejs` to our project which initially used only one concatenated js file without any modular system.

We noticed however that some UX changing scripts like `bootstrap-toggle` take longer to load even when used `r.js` optimizer with one concatenated js file which is  loaded from the browser cache.

Because of this user sees uninitialized state of some raw elements when heenters the page and only after 1-2 seconds the final look of the elements is rendered.

What can be done about this ?